# VS Code - How to create a method from angular html template?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, webstorm, shortcut

So, when I want to declare a new method in html of Angular component, WebStorm provides me opportunity to create this method in ts:
[image: Example webstorm]

But, if I try same at VS code I can't create a method.
Is there some solution? (extensions, maybe something in settings)
[image: Example vscode]

Comment: if you specify where and how to write this function I can modify the `My Code Actions` setting

Comment: @rioV8 I would say that need to create this function inside ts file related to html, they are connected at the directive via templateUrl for example @Component({templateUrl: './someFile.html' }) https://angular.io/guide/component-overview. Thank you for the hint, I'll take a look at the documentation of code actions and post an answer if all goes well.

Comment: so the `(click)="onToggle()"` is an html file and the ts file to change has the reference to the html file, than it will be very hard to specify the ts file to change in the action without scanning the whole workspace, if the ts and the html have the same filename but different extension I can add file variables that allow to construct the ts filepath based on the current file

Comment: @rioV8 So, you are right, in general angular components have same names for html, ts etc files

Comment: I have added the variable `${fileBasenameNoExtension}` in version 0.6.0, see updated answer, currently it adds at the start of the file, if you want it somewhere else you have to add a `where` and `???Find` properties

Comment: Tried updated to 0.6.0 now - doesn't seem like it adds any options to the quick fix menu? Is there any other config besides the snippet that should be added? @rioV8

Comment: the languageID of the file with the `(click)="onToggle()"` is most likely a HTML file. I changed the answer, If Angular templates have a different languageID fill that in

Comment: Copy the example again, there was a small typo (comma missing)

Comment: Yes, it is a HTML file. Still does not work with the latest example though... How does the fileBasenameNoExtension omit the extension? As Angular files are named like in this convention:
name.type.extension

So for a component the files would be named someName.component.ts, someName.component.html and someName.component.scss. If it just cuts the name after '.', that could be the issue perhaps? @rioV8

Comment: `${fileBasenameNoExtension}` finds the last `.` and removes it and everything after it, then by adding a new `.extension` you get a new filename. Is working for you now?

Comment: Well, yes and no, I guess. I found the reason why it didn't pop up - looks like it only supports native HTML events like (click), and I was testing it on an EventEmitter from Angular ((customSomething)). So looks like it won't work from any other contexts... @rioV8

Comment: Change the `"atCursor"` property, maybe change `click` with `[a-zA-Z]+`

Comment: Got it working for (emits) and [vars] - now to see if I can get it working for {{ interpolation }} ^^ Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 3):

This is now possible with the [VSCode Angular Language Service plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template) [v14.2.0](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/releases/tag/v14.2.0)

- feat: support fix the component missing member ([angular/angular#46764](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/46764))
- feat: support code action ([#1723](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/pull/1723))

[image: vscode angular code action]